# Outlook shows the Name associated with the email address in the From and To fields. How can I change that to see actual email address only?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

This applies to all versions of Outlook.  Since I'm using Outlook 2007 a solution for that version would be good.  The reason is I'm looking for a solution is that I get emails from people sometimes that is sent from either of 2 email addresses but they use their same name in their "sent from" setup.  All I can see in the inbox or sent folder is their header name, not their email address.  Of course if I open or preview their message, not a problem.  But there is no way to tell at a glance and the sort uses the "name" not the email.  Finally the the search feature doesn't restrict to the email address only.  For example Fred@gmail.com and Fred@acme.com.  A on From field will give both mixed together.  A search under Fred@gmail.com will give me all Freds regardless of gmail or acme.  Of course a search under gmail.com will give me all gmail entries - too much.
I've simplified the actual problem, hopefully in the interest of clarity instead of cluttering the question with a lot of whys and wherefores.
Thank you.

Comment: This is so ironic that you have two seperate logins and you're asking about people with multiple email address.

Answer (score 6):

Save the text below as **Email.cfg** (*Credit to SlipStick Systems* -[Source](http://www.slipstick.com/exs/customfields.htm))

```
;**********The CFG file********** 
[Description] 
MessageClass=IPM.Note.FromEmailAddress
CLSID={00020D31-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
DisplayName=Sender Email Address 
Category=Standard 
Subcategory=Form 
Comment=This forms allows the Senders E-mail address to be viewed as a 
column 
LargeIcon=IPML.ico 
SmallIcon=IPMS.ico 
Version=1.0 
Locale=enu 
Hidden=1 
Owner=Neostorm Systems 
Contact=Neo
[Platforms] 
Platform1=Win16 
Platform2=NTx86 
Platform9=Win95 
[Platform.Win16] 
CPU=ix86 
OSVersion=Win3.1 
[Platform.NTx86] 
CPU=ix86 
OSVersion=WinNT3.5 
[Platform.Win95] 
CPU=ix86 
OSVersion=Win95 
[Properties] 
Property01=FromEmailAddress 
[Property.FromEmailAddress] 
Type=30 
NmidInteger=0xc1f 
DisplayName=From E-mail Address 
[Verbs] 
Verb1=1 
[Verb.1] 
DisplayName=&Open 
Code=0 
Flags=0 
Attribs=2 
[Extensions] 
Extensions1=1 
[Extension.1] 
Type=30 
NmidPropset={00020D0C-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} 
NmidInteger=1 
Value=1000000000000000 
;**********END CFG
```

To install a cfg file:

1. Go to Tools, Options, Other, Advanced Options, Custom Forms, Manage Forms.
2. Click the Install button. Choose the.CFG file and install it into your Personal Forms Library
3. Click OK and return to the main Outlook screen
4. Right-click on the Column row in your Inbox (or other any other folder) and choose "Field Chooser"
5. Scroll down and choose "Forms"
6. Select Personal Forms, choose the Sender Email Address you added, then click Add
7. Add the field to your column headings to see the values.

Comment: Microsoft TechNet article describing the same procedure: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861109.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Delete all your contacts, that is where they are "resolved". 
Disassociate from any LDAP or GAL directory service..

There could be a reg setting too..

Wouldn't it be easier to just add a column to the display: "Email address" and remove the from column?